# The use of CommandLineArgs in visual studio

Tags: c#

So im trying to use CommandLineArgs.Count and CommandLineArgs.ToArray
If searched on the internet and they all say you use My.Application.CommandLineArgs but that does not work for me.

This is the error im getting

> Error 1   The name 'My' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Users\Nighel\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SOF_SCRIPT\SOF_SCRIPT\GUI.cs    119 17  SOF_SCRIPT

```
        if (My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] strArray = My.Application.CommandLineArgs.ToArray<string>();
            s = strArray[0];
            if ((strArray.Length == 3) | (strArray.Length == 4))
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't `My` a VB.NET thing?  Just use the `args` parameter from your `main` method.

Comment: If you aren't in the main method you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to save having to pass the args around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a string array containing the command-line arguments for the current process.

They are also available as parameters in the entry point of your application, `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Comment: So if i use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() my exe would be able to use the information my batch file throws at it when it opens it?